# Can't Subscribe to Platform Events using Pub/Sub API from Ruby

Tags: api, publish-subscribe

Struggling here and would love some advice - likely a configuration issue, but I can't seem to sort it out.

I think the basics of the service and auth are working fine - I can make the following call:

```
service.get_topic(Eventbus::V1::TopicRequest.new(topic_name: '/event/Test__e'), { metadata: })
```

... and I get a TopicInfo object in return.  Great!

However, when I try to subscribe to this topic and retrieve some events, I get nothing.  No error message, nothing - my script just completes and exits.  Here is the subscribe call:

```
op = service.subscribe(
  [Eventbus::V1::FetchRequest.new(topic_name: '/event/Test__e', replay_preset: 1,
                                  num_requested: 2)], { metadata: }) 
op.each do |response|
  puts 'Got message!'
  puts response.inspect
end
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?  I publish an event of this type before testing, so I know there is an event to be delivered.  I have tried different values for replay_preset, but have never gotten any return.

There are not a lot of examples on the web for pub/sub yet, and no examples that I could find using ruby.  Any ideas/assistance would be welcome.  Thank you!

Scott

ps I am testing in a sandbox environment associated with an unlimited edition production environment, in case that matters.